# memcpy takes virtual address or physical address?

Tags: c, camera, memcpy

I am working on Video HAL Application & there I am getting Camera frame CallBack from HAL Layer. During programming I found that memcpy copying data from physical address gets crashed while it is ok by copying data from **virtual address**. I searched for such a information about memcpy but found no where & even not on its man page.
so, my question is does memcpy required **physical address or virtual address**? Anywhere mentioned this type of information about memcpy?

Comment: Architecture dependent.

Comment: `memcpy` is part of the C library for user-space programs and these do not care about virtual or physical addresses. You have to check your OS kernel documentation for proper functions in the kernel address space.

Comment: @MartinJames  that means i need to go with my kernel documentation, right?

Comment: is there any reason for down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` is implemented in C or optimized in assembler. As such, it doesn't care about what type of address it gets. It just loads the addresses in the CPU registers and executes `mov` instructions.

It is the operating system and memory hardware architecture that are responsible for mapping any logical (virtual) address to a physical address.

Note also that with modern OS/memory architectures, each process gets its own address space. Passing addresses between address spaces will not work.

In these cases, the OS will probably provide functionality to exchange memory objects (shared or otherwise) between processes.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Ogilvie correctly explained, `memcpy` deals with user space addresses. As such they are virtual addresses, not necessarily physical addresses.

Yet there is a possibility for very large areas with very specific alignment characteristics to optimize `memcpy` by requesting the OS to remap some of the destination virtual addresses as duplicates of the physical memory mapped to the source addresses.  These pages would get the COPY_ON_WRITE attribute to ensure that the program only modifies pages in the appropriate array, if and when it writes to either one.  The *generic* implementation of `memcpy` in the GlibC does this (see `glibc-2.3.5/sysdeps/generic/memcpy.c`). But this is transparent for the programmer who still provides addresses in user space.